# create a columns with a value determined by the CASE result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers (
  num int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO numbers (num) VALUES
  ('1'),
  ('2'),
  ('3'),
  ('4'),
  ('5');
```

And this is what I want to get from it by adding another column with TRUE for 1 or 2 in num and FALSE for everything else:

```
| num | is_1_2
| --- | -------
| 1   | true
| 2   | true
| 3   | false
| 4   | false
| 5   | false
```

Here is my request

```
SELECT num, (CASE WHEN  num IN (1,2)  THEN 'true' ELSE 'false') AS is_1_2
FROM numbers
```

but I get

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near ') AS is_1_2 FROM numbers' at line 1

and could not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are forgetting end

```
SELECT num, (CASE WHEN  num IN (1,2)  THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS is_1_2
FROM numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running MySQL. If you are content with expressing true/false values as 1 and 0, you can simplify the query as:

```
select num, num in (1, 2) as is_1_2 from numbers
```

This takes advantage of the fact that MySQL evaluates a true condition as `1` and a false condition as `0` in numeric context.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed an END in the end. You can read more about CASE statements [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/case-statement-in-sql/)

```
SELECT 
 num, 
 is_1_2 = CASE 
   WHEN  num IN (1,2) 
   THEN 'true' 
   ELSE 'false' 
 END
FROM numbers
```